# Installing Vivaldi on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, deb

The debian package downloaded from the site opens in the software center, but when install is clicked it does nothing.

Guys the question does not ask how to install on ubuntu 15.04.  As you probably realize the procedure between implementations can easily differ.  Also the question does not ask how to install debian packages in general.  In the past my experience with this is that the general install mechanism does not pull dependencies, or has other tricky implementation details such as just use `-f` ... which in the past sometimes works, sometimes does not, and then we are back to the drawing board again, possibly having to reinstall the whole system in order to clean things up.

Context matters.  The context here is Ubuntu 17.04 (64 bit) and Vivaldi.  People coming to this forum want a tested proven answer in the context that they are requesting the answer for.  Short simple and easy to implement answers.

This is probably the 5th time this month that I'm writing a long explanation in my post as to why something is not a duplicate.  It will probably trigger something about going to meta to explain or challenge the duplicate tag.  But seriously we just want quick short answers.  Put a 3 day timing delay on marking things as duplicates and let people respond with answers that are specific to a given context.  It will make the forum much better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then download vivaldi and do:

```
sudo gdebi vivaldi-stable_1.9.818.50-1_amd64.deb
```

Same for google chrome:

```
gdebi google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Comment: You know you can install debs by command line without any additional software, don't you? If you didn't you know now. Installing GDebi, a GUI app to then use it in the command line is kinda ridiculous. Suggesting GDebi is fine but then use it as intended, by opening the debs with it, in a GUI.

Comment: It's a clean solution and just works.  In the past I have had problems with other installers requesting dependencies and failing.  If you have a cleaner tested solution that just works then feel free to post the answer and I will accept it.  People on the forum just want a quick solution that works.

Comment: If you look at some of the answers referenced they are very long.  Installing a browser should not be an exercise in hobby electronics.